# Reverse Engineering SCARA Style Robot - USB Protocol

Tags: wireshark

I am new to the topic of reverse engineering software (not new to hardware reverse engineering), so this question is more of a "lets ask people's opinion" type of thing.

I have a robot arm that my biology research lab wants to use for more than the companies software will let it. So I was tasked with writing our own code for controlling the robot so it can do more things.

Using Wireshark I can see it is made up of 1 USB hub that controls two cameras and two usb-serial converters. I would imagine that the USB-Serial converters are controlling the motors, but when I look at the data passing through those devices, I see a lot more than just data being sent when the robot arm moves.

The struggle is that the original software doesn't have a way to move individual arms so I can't simply move and arm and see what data is sent. It only completes compound movements and I am struggling to parse it all out.

Any advice for how to filter out some of the background noise and focus in on the actual control protocol?

Thank you!

Edit:

[image: This is a screenshot of what Wireshark says the robot contains inside of it. I would think that the communication to the joints would go through the USB-Serial converter]

This is a screenshot of what Wireshark says the robot contains inside of it. I would think that the communication to the joints would go through the USB-Serial converter

Comment: Can you get access to the software that drives the arm? I don't do any hardware fiddling, but I would guess you need simple movements to map the control codes?

Comment: @MegaTonnage Hey! Thank you for replying. And yeah I have access to the software that drives the robot and I do need simple movements to map the control codes, but the software only drives it in complicated compound movements that I cannot control. It only allows you to set up preconfigured compound movements and piecing that out is hard by just watching the Wireshark data I don't have the experience to decompile the .exe files that drive the arm, but I have looked into it.

Comment: No problems, maybe someone more hardware oriented will reply.

Comment: 1. what is the name of the robot/robot software?
2. try to come up with some test "complicated compound movements" that only change a single axis - what does change in the protocol, try to stabilize as much as possible - then some movements that only change a different axis - compare these two test-sets

Comment: @llm you can find the user manual at andrew-alliance.intercom-attachments-1.com It is a Generation 1 Andrew Pipetting Robot from AndrewAlliance.com. The simplest action I can make with the robot is tell it to move liquid from one tube to the one next to it. Then it runs its self through a setup phase, executes the movement and stops. So I will definitely try setting up two different motions and seeing what changes.

Comment: @llm What do you make of the Wireshark readout I added to the original question? I would think the data for the communication for the joints would pass through the serial to USB converter so it may help to filter out some of the data if I only look at those two channels?

Comment: @bcarroll14 - according to the wireshark - yes the serial stuff could be interesting - if it its clear that the USB connections stuff is really the robot, another question is: did you tried to contact the manufacturer of the robot and ask if there is a protocol description, seoncd: it really could be that detail robot movement is hidden - because there seems to be no real need to detail-control the robot from outside the device

Comment: @llm I did try to contact the R&D team that developed it and they were very secretive about their product so they wouldn't give any information. Second, I am beginning to think the same thing. I think I'll just have to take out the control board and install my own.